# Allowing users/administrators to update content management themselves

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, drupal

Is there an option besides Drupal or Wordpress to use to allow the user or administrators of a site to update and manage content on the site themselves?

Is it possible to use Drupal or Wordpress for a particular section of the site that I want to allow the above mentioned but not the rest of the site.

Basically I am just looking into options to be able to make the site from scratch:

1. without having to make it a drupal or wordpress template
2. without having to handbuild the content management system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

[Silverstripe](http://silverstripe.org/)

[Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)

[e107](http://e107.org)

Or you could have a look through here and find one that fits your needs: [opensourcecms.com](http://php.opensourcecms.com/)

There is another one that i have on the tip of my tongue thats really good... Ill pot it when i think of it! **EDIT**: Ahh HA... Got it :oP [e107](http://e107.org)

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://php.opensourcecms.com/

Answer (score 1):

[ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/overview/features/) might be the most flexible and powerful solution for your needs, in terms of supporting both static and dynamic sections/pages.  See also [this MetaFilter discussion.](http://ask.metafilter.com/125107/Best-CMS-for-a-static-website)